# Mac Web Browser URL Field issue

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, web, browser

so I have a Web Browser I am building on the Mac in `Xcode`, and currently I am able to navigate to URLs and do all the basic stuff.
However I want the URL bar to update every time I go to a new page.
EX. If I type `"yahoo.com"` into the URL bar, and then click on a link  to Yahoo mail, the URL bar doesn't update to `"mail.yahoo.com"`.

So my question is, *How would I go about fixing this?*

Answer (score 0):

Use the `webView:didStartProvisionalLoadForFrame:` delegate method in the `WebFrameLoadDelegate` protocol, which is called every time a new frame is loaded.